# How to delete inserted records without having a key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables: Tags and TagsTemp.

Tags has millions of rows while TagsTemp has thousands.

They both are physical tables.

The Primary Key in both tables is ID and it is Auto ID (and so IDs are in different numbers, they do not match).

I have to move all data from TagsTemp to Tags.

That is simple. I did this:

```
BEGIN TRANS
INSERT INTO Tags (C1, C2, C3)
SELECT C1, C2, C3 FROM TagsTemp

DELETE FROM TagsTemp

COMMIT
```

The problem is that TagsTemp could have new records during this transaction (during the time between the insert and the delete statements).

I do not want to delete table with records that were not inserted.

I was thinking of something like:

```
BEGIN TRANS
INSERT INTO @T (ID, C1, C2, C3)
SELECT ID, C1, C2, C3 FROM TagsTemp

INSERT INTO Tags (C1, C2, C3)
SELECT C1, C2, C3 FROM @T

DELETE FROM TagsTemp
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM @T)

COMMIT
```

But this is seems not the best way and bad performance.

Is there any better solution to do that?

**Note**: I cannot change Tables structure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a few thousand rows I think your solution is perfectly good, but just to let you know another approach, you can obtain the `MAX(ID)` from the table and then use that, assuming your auto IDs are incrementing ints:

```
BEGIN TRAN;

DECLARE @MaxId INT;

SELECT @MaxId = MAX(ID) from TagsTemp;

INSERT INTO Tags (C1, C2, C3)
SELECT C1, C2, C3
FROM TagsTemp
WHERE ID <= @MaxId;

DELETE
FROM TagsTemp
WHERE ID <= @MaxId;

COMMIT;
```

PS: Not sure about your `END TRANS` - I assume you mean `COMMIT`?

Answer (score 5):

Inspired by [Bart Hofland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4174789/bart-hofland) you can in fact capture the IDs of the records you are transferring during the insert, so long as you use a `MERGE` statement as your insert as follows:

```
DECLARE @IDs TABLE (ID INT PRIMARY KEY);

BEGIN TRAN;

MERGE Tags target
USING TagsTemp source
ON 0 = 1
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
INSERT (C1, C2, C3) VALUES (source.C1, source.C2, source.C3)
OUTPUT source.id INTO @IDs;

DELETE
FROM TagsTemp
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM @IDs);

COMMIT;
```

This allows a more flexible approach for when you are not basing your criteria on an auto-incrementing identity column.

Comment: This is actually a pretty smart solution as well. Nice. I am aware of the MERGE-statement, but I practically never use it because of its obscure syntax. But it might provide additional performance benefits, which seem to be important here. (With this, you now need only one statement instead of two for the insertion logic.)

Answer (score 4):

The other approaches are really just fine.  However, a different method would be to use partitioning.

This assumes that you have an `createdAt` date in the temp table.  Then, do the following:

- create a new partition on the table with the current date/time
- load the data from the temporary table using the current date/time
- drop the old partition

The major advantage to this approach is that dropping a partition should be much, much faster than deleting rows.

Comment: I have never used dropping partition, and I dont know what that is. can you help me with code?

Comment: @asmgx . . . I didn't include the detailed code because -- although much more efficient -- this requires more knowledge of a database than merely querying tables.  If you have a DBA around, you can ask them about partitions.

Answer (score 2):

The answer that [Dale K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1127428/dale-k) provided is excellent.

However, if you (ever) need to move records over based on other criteria than its auto-incrementing primary key, you could use a temporary table or a table variable that stores the keys to delete:

```
DECLARE @IDs TABLE (ID INT PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO @IDs (ID)
SELECT ID
FROM TagsTemp
---WHERE [whatever you want]

BEGIN TRAN;

INSERT INTO Tags (C1, C2, C3)
SELECT C1, C2, C3
FROM TagsTemp
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM @IDs);

DELETE
FROM TagsTemp
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM @IDs);

COMMIT;
```

With this logic, you can use any criteria in a WHERE-clause of the first SELECT-query.

Comment: @asmgx . . . I noticed that you already use such an approach using a temp table. Regarding the bad performance, please notice two things: I only store the ID in the temp table and I declare it as a primary key to allow indexing. With those changes in place, it should perform a lot faster. Otherwise, a temporary table (`CREATE TABLE #IDs (ID INT PRIMARY KEY)`) instead of a table variable might be another option to investigate.